# Display Settings Reset After Start Up

Tags: windows-vista, display-settings

Okay. Every time I start my computer the display settings reset to 800 by 600 pixels. I can change the settings to 1280 by 800 and it will stick while I'm using it. But as soon as I put it back to sleep it resets back to the lower display setting. I am running Windows Vista and using a Toshiba Satellite. Can anyone please help me keep my settings?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few suggestions for this elsewhere on the web that are not specific to toshiba satellite:

1. If you have the NVidia Control Panel, try using that instead of the windows control panel, it might stick better.
2. Reboot into safe mode and change your resolution there then reboot again and try in regular boot mode.
3. Upgrade or reinstall your display drivers.
4. There's something in Vista called the Windows Multimon Manager, if you disable that in the Task Scheduler it might fix the issue but it may also stop detecting it if you plug in or unplug external monitors.
5. Install ultramon and use that to set your resolution.
6. As a last resort, reinstall windows completely (or upgrade to Windows 7).

Cheers,

Dobes